# When is it appropriate to provide clickjacking protection one of my websites pages?

Tags: web-application, clickjacking

I run a couple of websites, so I'm just wondering what is the appropriate use of clickjacking protection like the x-frame-options response header? What pages are susceptible to this kind of attack on my users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, every page which allows the user to *change data* is a potential target for clickjacking. The goal of clickjacking is to trick the victim into taking actions on the attacker's behalf. This affects every page with forms or buttons or other UI elements which have persistent effects.

However, I strongly recommend against taking the blacklist approach and picking individual pages for protection. It's very easy to overlook something, the pages may change over time, and even a seemingly harmless page can become dangerous through an additional vulnerability. For example, the attacker might have found a cross-site scripting vulnerability on your site. By combining this with clickjacking, they may be able to take arbitrary actions regardless of what you originally designed the page for.

The correct approach is whitelisting: You protect *every* page except those which absolutely must be framed.

Note that setting the header to anything other than `DENY` isn't reliable. When faced with nested frames, current browsers usually just check the top-level site. This means you can end up with situations like this: You allow the site `good.com` to embed your page as a frame, but this site also embeds `evil.com`. This allows `evil.com` to frame your page *despite* the `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` header being set to `good.com`, because the top-level site is indeed `good.com`.

So if you do allow framing, expect the page to be framed on *any* site, not just the one you've chosen.

Comment: Just wanted to add that not all browsers support the X-Frame option. If you're concerned with protecting users with older browsers you need to include frame busting java script on the pages you want to protect.